# make editable div break line at end of div length

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm made a div editable using:

```
<div style="width:100px;" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

now, i'm putting the content of the div into my db and im extracting it into another page, into a smaller div:

```
<div style="width:80px;"></div>
```

if im using the "enter" key while typing - the text breaks lines just fine on the output,

but if im simply writing a long text in the output it leaves the 80px div border.

how can i make the contenteditable div recognize line breaks by its width?

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word;` try applying this style to your `<div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with:

```
<div style="max-width:80px; word-wrap:break-word;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div style="width:80px;word-wrap:break-word;"></div>
```